# Accessing Sql Server 2008 running on another machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I have a laptop that I would like to access the full suite (Analysis Services, Management Studio, etc...) from the laptop, but SQL Server 2008 will be running on my local server?  How can I accomplish this?  Do i have to install Sql Server 2008 on my laptop as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to access the server as a client then you should install SQL Server Management Studio on your laptop and register connections to the various server components on the server.  You don't have to install the full SQL Server suite, just management studio.

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, one does not need anything on machine to access a server except networking protocols already installed with any operating system.

Usually, all what is needed comes to end user with  setup of application he is intending to use or even without any setups through webapplications concept accessing database servers without any installation on client like, for ex., in this site